# django file upload, file select window keeps popping up

Tags: jquery, django, file-upload

I am using the file upload given [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html). The upload works fine on first load of the page (the upload field is in a modal ). If i try it again, the file select window keeps popping up on submission/cancel/close modal ,and upload doesn't seem to work.I can't find what's wrong. Pls Help.

**Edit**
I have replaced the default upload(one from the link) button with custom one.Templates in the 
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/83jsutye/7/)

```
views.py

class BasicUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(self.request, 'contacts/up.html')

    def post(self, request):
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)

def finalUpload(request,id):
    form=add_document_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        title=form.cleaned_data['title']
        document=form.cleaned_data['document']
        doc_related_to=form.cleaned_data['doc_related_to']
        doc_related_deals=form.cleaned_data['doc_related_deals']
        doc=documents(title=title,related_to=doc_related_to,rlated_deals=doc_related_deals,document=document)
        doc.save()
        obj = documents.objects.latest('id')
        for contact_id in obj.related_to:
            activityUpdate("document",obj.id,"1",contact_id,form.cleaned_data['title'],"0")
        Photo.objects.all().delete()
        return HttpResponse("done") 
    return HttpResponse(form)
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I've added the code.